# VisualOn Sdk implementation for amazon Fire TV App

Tags: android, video-streaming, amazon-fire-tv

I have implemented visualon sdk in my Amazon FireTV app to play m3u8 subtitled url.
But it does not play any of video url either m3u8 or mp4.

And i am getting error pop-up dialog showing media format not supported.

pthread_create sched_setscheduler call failed: Operation not permitted
12-03 08:31:33.530: V/Lab7 Player(9725): Error message, what is -2147483619 extra is 0
12-03 08:31:33.750: V/@@@VOCommonPlayerListener(9725): Async Open Finished...
12-03 08:31:33.750: V/Lab7 Player(9725): Error message, what is -2147483619 extra is 0

**Edit**
I have also uses following links :-

Download the final VisualOn license file here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/VO-SDK/voVidDec.dat

Download the VisualOn OnStream SDK zip file here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/developer-relations-av/Frameworks/VisualOn/VisualOnSDK.zip

Fire TV devices that license string is VISUALON-AMAZON-2014AAC0FC094236

Here is sample code for enabling the VisualOn license file:

```
InputStream is = null;
byte[] b = new byte[32*1024];
try {
    is = context.getAssets().open("voVidDec.dat");
    is.read(b);
    is.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
m_sdkPlayer.setLicenseContent(b);
m_sdkPlayer.setPreAgreedLicense("Amazon license string");
```

Any help/advice  will be appreciable

thanks

Comment: did you get the VO SDK from Amazon or somewhere else? Do you have correct license file and config?

Comment: yes i have downloaded it from developer.amazon.com and also get license from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **jni** files all are in the lib folder or not . and also check your license code is written before using it or not(Mean it must written before any of condition executed.).